# Most important documentation in the Iphone Dev Center

Tags: iphone, documentation

What is, according to you, the most important topic (chapter) covered by the iPhone Developer Documentation?

Do you know another topic that is very important to you, yet rarely read by other developers?

I would like to print and read some important chapters, but I may forget something...

Comment: The most important ones are the ones most related to what you are doing.

Comment: I agree, but what is the subject you like the most? Which chapter should be read by every developer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several core guides to important concepts.  These include:

- [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/)
- [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)
- [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/)
- [iPhone Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/000-Introduction/introduction.html)
- [iPhone Application Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/)
- [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/)
- [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html)
- [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iPhone OS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Accessibility_on_iPhone/Accessibility_on_iPhone.html)
- [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html)
- [Getting Started with Networking and Internet](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Networking_iPhone/index.html)
- [Interface Builder User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Instruments User Guide](https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/#/dev7b09c84f5)
- [Xcode Debugging Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html)

Many of these point to additional references that you may also like to read.

Comment: I have read most of them but i must say, its a great compilation. :) Vote up!

Comment: I would like to vote +1 in importance to :
 1. "Cocoa Fundamentals Guide"
 2. "iPhone Human Interface Guidelines"
 3. "View Controller Programming Guide for iPhone OS"
In that order.

Comment: I totally agree because what is important depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Every beginning iPhone developer gets tripped up by the deployment process.  I would print, memorize and feel comfortable with setting up profiles and such.  Here are some more essential concepts

- Memory Management
- Saving your dsym for later debugging
- Testing
- Buttoning up leaks and profiling

Each of these concepts can be searched for on Stack Overflow for more information.