# What are all the documents i need to read to become a iPhone developer?

Tags: iphone

I knew C, Cpp, Java, Servlets, JSP and Objective C. Now, i want to do some web related application in iPhone. I have Mac system, XCode and all. Also i registered in developer.apple.com. My problem is, where can i start to learn about development?

So many documents are available in Apple's site. But in each document, they gave a lot of links for other documents and said "before reading this read this" I just hate it.

So please give me a clear way to learn about iPhone development. Tell some other better sites for easy learning about SDK codings if you know...

Thank you all...

Comment: Get a book on the subject...?

Comment: What type of app you are going to build?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto articles for iPhone development, Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914429/most-important-documentation-in-the-iphone-dev-center and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405568/are-you-doing-iphone-development-how-do-you-learn

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apple documentation is wonderful.
Begin with [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/) to familiarize with the language and then take a look at [Your First iOS Application](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Start at a hello world and work your way up. The best way is to just purchase a book on the subject.

This one looks pretty basic http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-iPhone-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430224592/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1281003097&sr=8-1